# Explanation of Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Can anyone explain what is meaning of this Regular Expression?

```
/^(https?):\/\/(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3}[a-zA-Z0-9\-\#\.\/\?]*$/
```

Comment: please see answer of
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url"

Comment: The function is correct but not the url's that you've given. All these are not valid url's. :-)

Comment: https://www.x.xx

https://www.x.co

https://www.x.c

which is true url and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have founded my solution:

```
function validateURL(url) 
{
  var re = /^(https?):\/\/(www\.)?[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[[a-z0-9\-\.\/]{2,}]*$/;
    if (!re.test(url))
    { 
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

this function return true if your url contain these:
part 1. https or http
part 2. www or not (means optional).
Below image exploring in more depth.
```

[image]

I am wrong?

Comment: *return re.test(url);*

Comment: Where did you generated that image? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following and works fine for me.

```
var url = "https://www.xyz.xe";
function validateURL(url) 
{
  var urlregex = new RegExp("^(http|https)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
  return urlregex.test(url);
}
validateURL(url);
```

Returs false when `url="https://www.xyz.x"` and true when `url="https://www.xyz.xe"`